How do I set up Tight VNC on my office computers after installing the app on my remote computer?
I have downloaded Tight VNC on my computer however, I intended on downloading it on my office computers to view what my staffs are doing. Before I do so I want to know what else should I do on my end in order to have access to my office computers. I'm currently using Anydesk but I have request access each time from my staff and it does time out and the process repeats. Please anyone help me with Tight VNC.

Is this all on a local network? VNC comes in two forms server and viewer. Without making it too complicated, both viewer and server are installed when you run the insaller and set next on default throughout the installation. On each computer you install it on, you will need to set the password and make sure you note the port (I think its 5900). Default installation should set the vnc server on the device as a service, if you're installing on windows, so you should be able to enter the ip of that device from your computer and connect.
Please be aware VNC is generally not secure by default and depending on how many endpoints you plan on connecting to, can be tedious to maintain. I would suggest seeking alternatives, I think there are some free ones out there that are built on top of tight vnc.
Sorry for the late response, while it is possible to secure tight vnc standalone here is a list of other applications built on top of tight vnc with more features. Some paid, some free based on how many installations you will have.
Mighty Viewer- Linked from the tightvnc websites
UltraVnc- I believe the free version gives some extra controls and features
RealVNC
Free remote management alternatives to VNC
MeshCentral- Open Source - Easy to setup and secure, also has more features and good docs. Downside, the creator has moved on but has promised security updates.
Rust Desk- Open Source - Probably a bit more effort to setup, however, still actively worked on. There is a paid version, but I doubt you will need anything more than what the community version offers.

Yes it is on a local network. I set up the password on my remote computer but I haven't done it on the office computer as yet.  Can you provide a few of the other alternatives I could use please?

I edited my answer above
